# How to place dynamically items in form?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there in c# something like in css - `"float: left | right | none | inherit"`?
I want to display in my Form - `TextBox` and below each `TextBox` - `PictureBox`. So I don't know the size of each `TextBox`, it can be different, and in result my `PictureBoxes` cover `TextBoxes`....

```
 static int k = 1;

 for (int att = 0; att < feed.response.items[i].attachments.Count(); att++)
 {
     string switchCase = feed.response.items[i].attachments[att].type;
     switch (switchCase)
     {
         case "photo":                                          
             TextBox text = new TextBox();
             text.Text =Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(feed.response.items[i].text));
             Point p = new Point(20, 30 * k);
             text.Location = p;
             this.Controls.Add(text);

             PictureBox mypic = new PictureBox();
             mypic.ImageLocation =  feed.response.items[i].attachments[att].photo.photo_130;
             mypic.Size = new Size(100, 100);
             Point g = new Point(40, 160 * k);
             mypic.Location = g;
             this.Controls.Add(mypic);
             k++;
             break;
....
    }
}
```

Comment: try using google and search for how to add controls dynamically to a form winforms C#

Comment: I would use a gridlayout for this kind of stuff

Comment: You probably want [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) with the `ColumnCount` property set to `1`. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably illustrates your scenario, it's hard to say for sure, never mind to provide a useful answer with code example.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by [Peter Duniho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740753/how-to-place-dynamically-items-in-form#comment49545893_30740753) you can use two TableLayoutPanels, one added at design-time to your form. The other is dynamically created and populated with the right controls to achieve what you want. Your code would look like this:

```
private void AddOne()
{
    // create a new tablelayoutpanel
    // with 2 rows, 1 column
    var table = new TableLayoutPanel();
    table.RowCount = 2;
    table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
    table.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
    table.ColumnCount = 1;
    table.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // take all space

    // create a label, notice the Anchor setting
    var lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "lorem ipsum\r\nnext line\r\nthree";
    lbl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    // add to the first row
    table.Controls.Add(lbl, 0, 0);

    // create the picturebox
    var pict = new PictureBox();
    pict.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(@"demo.png");
    pict.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
    pict.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
    // add to the second row
    table.Controls.Add(pict, 0, 1);

    //add the table to the main table that is on the form
    mainTable.Controls.Add(table, 0, mainTable.RowCount);
    // increase the rowcount...
    mainTable.RowCount++;

}
```

You'll have use the [Dock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Anchor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx) properties as well as the AutoSize property to have the Layout engine of the framework do all the heavy lifting for you.

You'll end-up with something that looks like this:

[image: table layout panel with two rows]